# Issue related to upgrading application related to Database in Android

Tags: android, apk

When i modify the database and upgrade the existing app in my Phone, the DB is not getting overwritten which makes my application crash.
How to tell phone to delete the DB and add fresh one during installation of APK file?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to increase the version number you pass to the the `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html